# Xcode Build Errors regarding DerivedData folder (File Write Create Error)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I accidentally deleted the DerivedData folder, not only its files.

> Applying this command "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"

> Instead of this command "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/"

After that Xcode started to return following errors.

> Error # 1 : Sandbox: rsync.samba(12046) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/mycompany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfdtmaowyaodbagkvttzeqjhiwjl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework

> Error # 2 : Sandbox: dart(12019) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/mycompany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfdtmaowyaodbagkvttzeqjhiwjl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/.last_build_id

> Error # 3 : Flutter failed to write to a file at "/Users/mycompany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfdtmaowyaodbagkvttzeqjhiwjl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/.last_build_id".

I also run following commands (not in order, while trying to solve it by myself)

- pod cache clean --all
- pod install --repo-update
- pod install

Because of those errors Xcode can't build the app.

Here is the version information of my development environment.

- Flutter - Stable channel - 3.16.7 on Macos 14.2.1 darwin-arm64
- Dart - 3.2.4
- Devtools 2.28.5
- Platform Android 33, build tools 34.0.0
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
- Android Studio 2023.1
- Xcode 15.2
- CocoaPods 1.12.0

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Never any issue with deleting the DerivedData folder. If it's not there Xcode will recreate it. Did you try a Product > Clean Build Folder in Xcode and/or simply restarting Xcode?

Comment: Yes I did for many times. (Clean Build Folder, restarting xCode, flutter clean etc.) As I understand DerivedData is not an app specific folder, brand new applications don't return this error. The only reason I suspect is because error messages addressing this folder.

Comment: Actually I may have a clue about this. I changed Runner > Build Settings > Quoted Include in Framework Header value to NO (I did it to solve some issues comes from revenuecat plug-in) Now I change it to YES and two of errors has gone. Only Error #3 remained in the list.

Comment: I will close this question. Because I made some changes to solve RevenueCat problems (Changing the value of "Runner > Build Settings > Quoted Include in Framework Header" from YES to NO), when I revert this change, 3 of the problems are gone. 

The problem was solved after commenting that deleting DerivedData would not cause such a problem.

Thank you very much.